# A single forward slash in CSS: Is this some browser-specific thing?

Tags: css

I inherited a CSS style sheet, and in a few places it does things like:

```
margin:7px 0 0 0;
/margin-top:9px;
```

Or

```
background: url(../images/list-hover.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
/background:url(../images/lists-hover.png) 0 2px no-repeat;
```

What is that forward slash doing?

Comment: That's one hack I've never encountered. But CSS3-specific? Nah. It's not even valid CSS. Retagged.

Comment: Never seen that either. I know `_margin: ...` for IE6 and `*margin: ...` for IE7. It's definitely not correct CSS syntax =)

Comment: @Rudie: It's `_` for IE6 and `*` for IE6/7.

Comment: @BoltClock Oops, my bad. (I edited for safety..) I don't use either anymore. If you're using IE < 8, you don't deserve internet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's to target LTE IE7. This hack isn't known as much as the IE6 underscore one.

```
    #myelement {
background:red; /*Should show as red in all browsers, expect IE6 and IE7 because...*/
/background:yellow; /*IE7 should have yellow*/
_background:green; /*IE6 should have green*/
}
```

You can make the backslash almost anything you want really, expect the underscore _ as that will target IE6. I use the $ personally.

EDIT:
I've included the IE6 trick too there, as **anything IE7 and below** will take the / property unless you also have an _ property too.

To target IE8, IE7, and IE6 you need to have that order above.

Comment: Only IE7, not any earlier or later version? Also, the OP is correct, it's a forward slash.

Comment: +1 was just doing the same test (red/yellow bg) :) IE7 shows up yellow

Comment: @BoltClock actually IE 5.5 & 6 also took the yellow BG

Comment: @mdmullinax: Then that makes it no different from `*background`. To target only IE7 one would use the `* + html #myelement` selector.

Comment: Hi BoltClock, thanks for that, I should be more specific, IE7 and below unless you also have an IE6 _ property.