# Safari is showing the background color and image

Tags: html, css

I have using the following CSS for background design, It is working in all browsers but Safari is not showing the background color and image. Am I missing anything?

```
background: url("https://xyz.xyz.com/src/images/HeaderBackground.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 / 200px 94px #E2DDD5;
```

Please advice me..

Comment: It works fine for me on Safari 7, but it may be this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794804/forward-slash-in-css-is-this-some-browser-specific-thing

Comment: i faced this issue long time back......the only remedy was to duplicate the css ....for more info,check out this forum:-http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?302958-Background-image-doesn-t-show-up-in-Safari!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.background{
    background: url(images/background.png);
    background-repeat:repeat;
    width:500px;
    background-color:#E2DDD5;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    background-position:200px 94px;
    }
```

This code is working in safari. I thing usefull for you.